# MYSQL SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am getting the following MYSQL error message.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET BusRunDetailsID, BusRunDetails.BusRunID SET BusRunID, BusRunDetails.Meterag' at line 1
```

---

```
"SELECT [BUSRUNDETAILS.busrundetailsid] as busrundetailsid, ".
" [BUSRUNDETAILS.BUSRUNID] as busrunid, round(BUSRUNDETAILS.Meterage,2) as max_meterage, ".
" BUSRUNDETAILS.StopNo as max_stopno ".
" FROM BUSRUNDETAILS INNER JOIN ".
" [SELECT r.BUSRUNID, max(R.STOPNO) As MAXSTOP ".
" FROM BUSRUNDETAILS AS R ".
" GROUP BY R.BUSRUNID]. AS T2 ON ".
"(BUSRUNDETAILS.StopNo = T2.maxstop) AND ".
"(BUSRUNDETAILS.BusRunId = T2.BUSRUNID)"
```

Suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you use to generate this SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

`]. AS` is not a SQL correct expression (it seems that you are using microsoft access to create your SQL)

```
SELECT [BUSRUNDETAILS.busrundetailsid] as busrundetailsid,
       [BUSRUNDETAILS.BUSRUNID] as busrunid, 
       round(BUSRUNDETAILS.Meterage,2) as max_meterage, 
       BUSRUNDETAILS.StopNo as max_stopno 
FROM BUSRUNDETAILS 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT r.BUSRUNID, 
            max(R.STOPNO) As MAXSTOP 
     FROM BUSRUNDETAILS AS R 
     GROUP BY R.BUSRUNID) AS T2 
ON (BUSRUNDETAILS.StopNo = T2.maxstop) 
AND (BUSRUNDETAILS.BusRunId = T2.BUSRUNID)
```